# Get id of node that i'm selecting

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Now i can print all of the id of nodes using.

```
var idz = nodes.getIds();
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = idz;
```

I want to get the id of node that I am clicking what method that I have to use ?

The document is [here](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html#Getting_Data).

Comment: Where is your click event ?

Comment: network.on("selectNode", function (params) {
        console.log('selectNode Event:', params);
    });

Comment: im working on the example interactionEvents file of vis.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906493/accessing-node-data-in-vis-js-click-handler I got the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` reference.

Get id of current element

```
var currentElementId = this.id;
```